# Creating a java program that takes user input for an array and then using my own number and multiplying it by each day

Tags: java, arrays

Essentially, I am asking the user for an input of how manys days they would like something to happen (array). Once the user inputs that amount, I must make it to where it will display the number 1 for the first number they inputed and then have a set way of multipying each number after by 2. What I am having a hard time understanding is how I can correlate the user input array to the exact amount of the array I am going to create. My code so far.

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

int num = keyboard.nextInt();
int[] daysOfRice = new int[num];

for (int i = 0; i < daysOfRice.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(daysOfRice);
}

System.out.print(daysOfRice);
```

Comment: You haven't populated `daysOfRice` (and arrays don't override `toString` from `Object`). You can use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(daysOfRice));` to print the values from the array (but you'll have `0` `num` times).

Comment: Intresting, you may have just given me the idea for a PPCG code golf challenge, assuming its not already been done. The classic 2x grains of rice story. The recursive formula is `f(x) = f(x-1) * 2`

Comment: int i = 2;
 
 while(i <= daysOfRice.length)
 {
  if (i == 1)
  {
   int sum = 1;
   
  }
  int sum = i * 2;
  System.out.println("Day " + i + ": " + sum + " grains of rice are given");
  i++;
 }

Comment: With the above line of code, how do I make to to where it will display Day 1 as "Day 1: 1 grain of rice" then multiply it by 2 from there on out

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly is your requirement, have a look:

```
public class TestC {        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);    
        int num = keyboard.nextInt();
        keyboard.close();
        int[] daysOfRice = new int[num];
        int prod = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= daysOfRice.length; i++) {
            if (i == 1) {
                prod = 1;
            } else {
                prod = prod * 2;
            }
            System.out.println("Day " + i + ": " + prod
                    + " grains of rice are given");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is close but I am looking to make the second day 2 and then the followings days will be the previous # of rice multiplied by two. Day 1: 1 grain of rice; Day 2: 2 grains of rice; Day 3: 4 grains of rice; Day 4: 8 grains of rice

Comment: I have modified the program accordingly. It can be improved using recursion.